# How to create a json string in protractor from values in a dropdown

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

Say you've got a dropdown that you wish to verify.  A decent method (correct me if I'm wrong) is to compare the values against a JSON array (stringified) of expected values.

```
<select>
  <option value="--">Pick a State</option>
  <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
  <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
  ...
</select>
```

I have finally figured out how to get the "value" attribute and the text value, particularly from an array. (Not an easy feat for the beginning javascript guy.)

Anyway, I have worked it out to:

```
var actual = [];
$$('select option').each( function(el) {
  var name = '';
  var abbrev = '';

  el.getText().then(function(s) { 
    name = s; 
  }); 

  el.getAttribute('value').then(function (val) { 
    console.log("val = {"+val+"}"); 
    abbrev = val; 
  });

  console.log("abbrev = {"+abbrev+"}");  
  arr.push({ "name": name, "abbreviation": abbrev 
});
```

The result comes out as you may expect... well those who are very familiar.

```
abbrev = {}
abbrev = {}
abbrev = {}
val = {--}
val = {AL}
val = {AK}
```

And `actual` looks like:

```
[ 
  { name: '', abbreviation: '' },
  { name: '', abbreviation: '' },
  { name: '', abbreviation: '' } 
]
```

As can be seen, the `.then` method happens after its containing block has completed execution.

My question is, how do I go about fixing it so that I can get a result of:

```
[
  { "name": "Pick your State", "abbreviation": "--" },
  { "name": "Alabama", "abbreviation": "AL" },
  { "name": "Alaska", "abbreviation": "AK" }
]
```

NOTE:
For others who may happen upon this question in the future:
`$$('')` is shorthand and equivalent to (as far as I know) `element.all(by.css(''))`.  And `$('')` is shorthand for `element(by.css(''))`

**UPDATE:**

I've got it almost figured out.

```
var actual = []; 
ddOption.each(function(el) { 
  actual.push({ 
    "name": el.getText().then(function(s) { return s; }), 
    "abbreviation": el.getAttribute('value').then(function(s) { return s; }) 
  }); 
});
```

So, when I do a call, such as `actual[2].name` I get `Alaska` in return and `actual[2].abbreviation` gives me `AK`.
However, if I try to put that into a string

```
actual[2].abbreviation + ' = ' + actual[2].name
```

I get the Promise information as a string. Same when I try actual[2].name.valueOf().

```
ManagedPromise::1372 {[[PromiseStatus]]: "fulfilled"} = ManagedPromise::1363 {[[PromiseStatus]]: "fulfilled"}
```

How do I convert the returned value of a promise as a string?

**LIVE EXAMPLE:**

One can produce a live example of what I'm trying to do.

1. Start protractor in elementExplorer: `protractor --elementExplorer`
2. Disabled synchronization (the page we're going to has the angular app in an iFrame): `browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;`
3. Get the page: `browser.driver.get('http://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_select')`
4. Switch to the iframe: `browser.switchTo().frame('iframeResult')`
5. Set ddOption: `var ddOption = $$('select option')`
6. All in one line (because elementExplorer doesn't handle multiline commands... at least not in a way that I can tell), we're going to reset `actual` and then do the magic (the breakdown of the single line is shown above in the update):
   `var actual = []; ddOption.each( function(el) { actual.push({ "name": el.getText().then(function(s) { return s; }), "abbreviation": el.getAttribute('value').then(function(s) { return s; }) }); });`

   7. Type `actual[1].name` and get `Emil` as an output
   8. Type `actual[1].name + ' = ' + actual[1].abbreviation` and get the following as an output. `ManagedPromise::929 {[[PromiseStatus]]: "fulfilled"} = ManagedPromise::938 {[[PromiseStatus]]: "fulfilled"}` where I was hoping to get `Emil = string:Emil`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wait for your promises to resolve before pushing the array, in jQuery I use the $.when method to join promises you should find the equivalent within your deferred library implementation. With protractor it might look like this.

```
protractor.promise.all([promise1,promise2]).then(function(){
  //array push logic
}
```

The full code should look something like this:

```
var actual = [];
$$('select option').each( function(el) {
  var name = '';
  var abbrev = '';

  var promise1 = el.getText().then(function(s) { 
    name = s; 
  }); 

  var promise2 = el.getAttribute('value').then(function (val) { 
    console.log("val = {"+val+"}"); 
    abbrev = val; 
  });

  protractor.promise.all([promise1,promise2]).then(function(){
    console.log("abbrev = {"+abbrev+"}");  
    arr.push({ "name": name, "abbreviation": abbrev  });
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. When I tried a `.when` I got TypeError.  I probably used it in the wrong place.  As it is, I'm really close.  See the update in my question.

Comment: to get the result of a promise you subscribe to it, if it has already been fulfilled the callback will be invoked immediately, even in this scenario you should merge your promises before printing the results, can you send me your code for $q.when that is giving a type error? Maybe I can help you fix it?

Comment: I added instructions for a live example up in the question.  Thank you for spending time and helping me with this.

Comment: Looks like you aren't actually using angular promises, you are using webdriver promises as exposed via protractor, I have updated my answer try it and see how it works.

Comment: Does it matter if it is Angular 2 that I'm working in as opposed to Angular 1?

Comment: It shouldn't, the promises are generated via protractor when you call el.getText() and protractor generates promises via webdriver, angular should have no impact on the promises here.

Comment: @Machtyn I've added a solution in the context of your problem, you may need to work out a solution for protractor being out of scope in your particular project, but otherwise it should be what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks, 42shadow42.  I was getting close to the solution that you provided.  I think I had a couple of mistakes. I'll be taking a closer look on Monday.